# Is there a way to change the Language of the Automated Process User?

Tags: translation, language, automated-process

We have a process that's capturing error messages in a log object. Our error messages are contained in custom labels with translations, but everything initiated by the Automated Process user pulls in the english translations.

How could we default the Automated Process User to a different language?

Answer (score 1):

turns out setting the default org language does the trick.

article: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000325737&type=1

*Click Setup | Administration Setup | Company Profile | Company Information | Edit (Classic) OR Setup | Company Information (Lightning) and change the 'Default Language,' 'Default Locale,' and 'Currency Locale.' All new users will inherit these 'Language and Locale' settings.*